# batch file to rename folders creates new folders

Tags: command-line, batch, rename, batch-rename

Because I have multiple back-up copies of all files, I use the following batch file to rename files so that I don't have to go into each drive/folder to rename files manually. The batch file works fine for renaming files. However, when renaming folders, sometimes it works, the other time, it generates another folder with the corrected name. When this happens, it doesn't happen to every folders to be renamed, only some of the folders.

Is there something wrong with the batch file? How can it be corrected?

```
chcp 65001

if exist C:\rename-all-4.txt del c:\rename-all-4.txt

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%A in ('"TYPE C:\RENAME-ALL.txt"') do ( 
    echo %%A | find /i "\" 
    if errorlevel 1 (
        RENAME "D:\!mypath!%%A" "%%B" 
        RENAME "E:\!mypath!%%A" "%%B" 
        RENAME "\\PC1\D\!mypath!%%A" "%%B" 
        RENAME "\\PC1\E\!mypath!%%A" "%%B" 
 )  ELSE (
        echo "found pattern"
        echo %%A
        set mypath=%%A
        echo mypath is !mypath!
 )
)
) >> C:\RENAME-ALL-4.txt 2>&1
endlocal

CD /D C:\
```

The following is a shortened input file. After running the batch file, the original folder (中国人民银行_files) still exists along with a new folder (中國人民銀行_files).

```
News\
中国人民银行_files;中國人民銀行_files
```

Comment: @ It If a line in the input file ends with a slash, that's a path. There can be multiple paths in the input file and multiple folders/files (to be renamed) under a path. The example above only has one path "News\".

Comment: Start by properly indenting: to make it readable. I would do it for you, but I don't know this scripting language well.

Comment: Consider using Larry Wall's `rename` command. It will do it for you. On Debian systems you can install it with `apt install rename`.

Comment: @ ctrl-alt-delor I have edited the file with proper indentation. My batch file would rename folders but not always and I cannot tell when it'll rename and when it'll create new folders.

Comment: The listing in your looped file always obeys the order, first a line containing the name of a **`folder\ `**, and the line afterwards containing file names: **`fileX;fileY`**?

Comment: @ It yes. As seen in the sample file, Path name ends with a slash. It is followed by `file1;file2`. There may be several lines (several files to be renamed) after the path and there may be many paths in an input file. There are blank lines here and there, even at the beginning of the file. I don't think blank lines matter. There is no `mkdir` or anything like that in the batch. That's why I am puzzled as to why new folders are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "%~dp0" & >nul chcp 65001
2>nul del/q /f .\rename-all-4.txt 

>> .\rename-all-4.txt 2>&1 ( 
    for /f tokens^=1-2^delims^=^; %%a in ('
    type c:\rename-all.txt')do echo=%%~a|>nul findstr /e \ && (
         echo="found pattern" && echo=%%~a
         set "mypath=%%~a" && call echo=mypath is !mypath!
        ) || (
         ren "d:\!mypath!%%~a" "%%~b"
         ren "e:\!mypath!%%~a" "%%~b"
         ren "\\pc1\d\!mypath!%%~a" "%%~b"
         ren "\\pc1\e\!mypath!%%~a" "%%~b"
    )) 

endlocal && CD /D C:\
```

---

- This is an incorrect syntax:

```bat
if errorlevel  1 ... 
if errorlevel ????  1 ...

    errorlevel   equal integer :: 
if !errorlevel!  equ   1 ...
if %errorlevel%  equ   1 ...
```

---

Also, try to replace `errorlevel` condition to operators `&&` and `||`

---

- About using `errorlevel` in `.bat` vs `.cmd` file.

  - ```bat
    Old style .bat Batch files vs .cmd Batch scripts.
    There is a key difference between the way .CMD and .BAT batch files
    set errorlevels
    ```
  - ```bat
    A .BAT batch script running the 'new' internal commands:
    APPEND, ASSOC, PATH, PROMPT, FTYPE and SET will only set ERRORLEVEL
    if an error occurs. So if you have two commands in the batch script
    and the first fails, the ERRORLEVEL will remain set even after the
    second command succeeds.
    ```


    <sup>Source linked to **ss64.com**</sup>

---

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[If](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

  [√] **[Find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[!ErrorLevel! %Errorlevel%](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√] **[Understanding start, 2>nul, cmd, and other symbols in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598997/understanding-start-2nul-cmd-and-other-symbols-in-a-batch-file#:%7E:text=A%20command%20can%20output%20to,So%20nothing%20will%20be%20outputted.&text=Line%204%3A%20hard%20to%20tell%20without%20seeing%20rest%20of%20script.)**

Comment: You have changed your answer. Ｉwonder why. The old one works fine for me.

Comment: The old only print in screen

Comment: @joehua I just remove `echo`

Comment: The old one has this `do if "%%B"==""`, which I though was brilliant.

Comment: @joehua Where is this: **[`if "%%B"==""`](https://superuser.com/posts/1616142/revisions)**

Comment: Please see the answer I just posted. I'd post it as comment but didn't think comment can handle the format.

Answer (score 1):

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%A in ('"TYPE C:\RENAME-ALL.txt"') do if "%%B"=="" (
  echo "found pattern"
  echo %%A
  set  "mypath=%%A"
  echo mypath is !mypath!
 ) ELSE (
 RENAME "D:\!mypath!%%A" "%%B" 
RENAME "E:\!mypath!%%A" "%%B" 
RENAME "\\USER-PC1\D\!mypath!%%A" "%%B" 
RENAME "\\USER-PC1\E\!mypath!%%A" "%%B" 
 )
) >> C:\RENAME-ALL-4.txt 2>&1
endlocal
```